# Mockito with void method in JUnit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

I have implemented a simple spring boot crud application to write test cases. I have faced a bit of trouble with the delete operation. When I use `Mockito.when` method then it is expected a return value and my delete method is non-return type.

**Service Class**

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl  implements EmployeeService {

    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeDAO employeeDAO)
    {
        this.employeeDAO=employeeDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp) throws IllegalArgumentException{
             employeeDAO.delete(emp);
    }

}
```

**ServiceTest class**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class EmployeeServiceImplTest {

    @MockBean
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

@Test
public void testDeleteEmployee()
{
    int empId=1054;
    Employee employee=employee_2();
    employee.setEmpId(empId);

   // how to write test case for void method
}

private Employee employee_2()
    {
        Employee employee=new Employee();
        employee.setEmpName("NafazBenzema");
        employee.setSalary(12000.00);

        return employee;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can either use doNothing or doThrow on your mock to mock the behaviour of your mock.

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(employeeDAO).delete(any());
```

or

```
Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(employeeDAO).delete(any());
```

However, doNothing is not actually needed as this would be the default behaviour for a mock function with a void return type.
You may want however to `verify` that this method was called. For example:

```
verify(employeeDAO).delete(any());
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Mockito.doNothing()`:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(employeeDAO).deleteEmployee(Mockito.any());
```

Comment: what is any() method? where is it belongs?

Comment: when i use your code then `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:` 
has occurred

Answer (score 0):

Thank you omer.

But in my case, I had to replace `employeeService` with `employeeDAO`.The `employeeService` is annotated with `@Autowired` annotation and it throws `NotaMockAnnotation` exception.

```
   Mockito.doNothing().when(employeeDAO).delete(employee);
```

Comment: since you are testing EmployeeService, then it doesn't make sense to mock EmployeeService itself as that defeats the purpose. You would want to mock the dependency not the class/method under test

Comment: Also if you're going to mock the behavior of the dependencies of the class then I would recommend using unit test instead of integration test as u do in your example.